# Insert List into Database Linq - to - Entities

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

how to Insert List in to Database ?

```
public IEnumerable<STACK_DATA> Stack_Data()
{
    using (var context = new WSGPVEntities())
    {
        var query = (from cust in context.STACK_DATA
                     select cust);

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

I have some functions of this type, and wanted to get this List and add in another database.

Keeping the same table name and columns.

in summary ... I want to mirror each other tables in the database. Doing this in a thread.

Comment: So do you want to create the other database? or it's already created?

Comment: it already exists, but clean. 

I think that I can also create tables manually, but wanted to add a function to this

Comment: If the second DB already exists, mirrors the first, and has a `DbContext`, just new up the second `DbContext` and add each item into the appropriate `DbSet` and call `SaveChanges` on the `DbContext`.

Comment: I have 2 Models Created 2 different databases.. 
Queries returning lists. 
I do not know how to put it all .. Any example of DBContext?

Comment: Relations 
http://oi62.tinypic.com/2j4ysmc.jpg
tables 
http://oi59.tinypic.com/2628hsz.jpg
 and tables i need
http://oi59.tinypic.com/14o1uab.jpg

Comment: with this function i get one list...
///
 public IEnumerable<STACK_DATA> Stack_Data()
        {
            using (var context = new WSGPVEntities())
            {
                var query = (from cust in context.STACK_DATA
                             select cust);

                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
////
i'm trying to insert this list on database.
before do it on process to run automatically

Comment: Sorry, I meant show us your relevant models and edit your answer with text instead of linking images. You have `STACK_DATA` and you mentioned you have another model that you want the STACK_DATA to convert into and save to another db. I want to see `STACK_DATA` and that other nameless model.